# Woocommerce Pagination Not Rendering

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement pagination with the products shortcode.

```
do_shortcode( '[products category="'.$a.'" paginate="true" limit="8" columns="4"]')
```

The result follows other arguments like products are limited to 8 and layout 4 columns, but not pagination. Is this related to a theme restriction? Anyway, the result doesn't contain any pagination links. please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there are enough products in this category?

Comment: Yes, I've 70 products.

Comment: I have tested your shortcode and I have the pagination, so the problem is something else.

Comment: Is the theme has anything to do with pagination not displaying? I use enfold theme.